# How to find all indexs where Array value is equal to a number fsharp?

Tags: f#

I am trying to find a way to get all the instances where the array equals a certain value. I am able to get the first and last value as shown in my test case below but I am trying to get the middle value as well.

```
let test = [|"1";"2";"4";"2";"6";"2";"9";"10"|]
test
|> Array.findIndex(fun x -> x = "2")

test
|> Array.findIndexBack(fun x -> x = "2")
```

How do I get a list of all indexs?

Comment: You can use the [Array.mapi](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html#mapi) function

Comment: How would you use that in this case?

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick

```
let findAllIndexes predicate arr =
    Array.indexed arr
    |> Array.choose (fun (i, x) ->
        if predicate x then Some i else None)
```

Use it like this

```
test |> findAllIndexes (fun x -> x = "2")
```

which returns `[|1; 3; 5|]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.mapi` or `Array.indexed` to create an array of tuples that bind the values to their indexes.

```
let test = [|"1";"2";"4";"2";"6";"2";"9";"10"|]

//first option
let res' =
    test
    |> Array.mapi (fun i el -> i, el)
    |> Array.filter(fun el -> snd el = "2")
    |> Array.map fst

printfn "%A" res'

//second option
let res'' =
    test
    |> Array.indexed
    |> Array.filter(fun el -> snd el = "2")
    |> Array.map fst

printfn "%A" res''
```

These are just two of many options.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to achieve best performance consider this solution:

```ml
let indexes_resize predicate (ar: 'a []) =
    let res = ResizeArray()
    let mutable i = 0
    for el in ar do
        if predicate el then
            res.Add i
        i <- i + 1
    res
```

It uses `System.Collection.Generic.List<T>` as accumulator, so insert is very fast `O(1)`

Or if you want more idiomatic approach consider these

```ml
let indexes_rec predicate (ar: 'a []) =
    let rec inner acc index =
        if index = ar.Length - 1 then
            acc
        elif predicate ar.[index] then
            inner (index :: acc) (index + 1)
        else
            inner acc (index + 1)
    if ar.Length > 0 then
        inner [] 0 |> List.rev
    else []

let indexes_rec_generic predicate (seq: #seq<'a>) =
    let it = seq.GetEnumerator()
    let rec inner acc index =
        if it.MoveNext() then
            if predicate it.Current then
                inner (index :: acc) (index + 1)
            else
                inner acc (index + 1)
        else acc

    inner [] 0 |> List.rev
```

Both are using same technique with linked list as accumulator. While first suitable only for array, last can be used for any sequence but have performance penalty